# Header() seemingly being ignored or overwritten

Tags: php, http-headers, request-headers

Sorry for the length of this post but I want to provide as much detail as I can.  I am new to stackoverflow but have found comments made here useful in the past so I am hoping someone can just point me in the right direction.  We have a Linux server running php4.3.9.

Our clients can up load documents and then download them later by clicking on a link.  Clicking the link runs a php script which looks the document up in the database and then sets the headers, reads the file and downloads to the clients computer.  Works perfectly.  We had some programming done to create a word document on the fly which we wanted to work the same way but when we added the link to our site and clicked on it, it just outputs garbage in the browser window even though the headers have been set so it is a word document and should be downloaded.

After messing around with it for too long, I decided I would take the code that I know works for downloading other documents and literally replace everything in the new file with the content from the download file I know works.  So new php file we had created we wiped out and replaced with the code from the download file that works so they are identical except for the php file name.  I uploaded it again and it still did not work.  So I have identical php files in the same directory pointing to the same document to download and in one instance it works and in one instance it does not.

I then using web-sniffer.net to look at the headers and found this for the file that works:

```
HTTP Response Header
Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Wed, 02 Apr 2014 18:50:53 GMT   
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat) 
X-Powered-By:   PHP/4.3.9   
Content-Disposition:    attachment; filename=test.docx  
Connection: close   
Content-Type:   application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

...and for the identical file just in another place that does not work...

```
HTTP Response Header
Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Wed, 02 Apr 2014 18:51:15 GMT   
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat) 
X-Powered-By:   PHP/4.3.9   
Connection: close   
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The code is identical but in once case the Content-Dispostion and Content-Type headers are not being sent or replaced or something, causing the contents or the (word) document to display in the browser as garbage while it the other instances downloads no problem????  I have cleared caches, tried different browsers, different computers with the same result.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Just to be sure, the code in both places is exactly the same.  I copied and pasted it from the working php file to the new php file.  I even copied the link from the place that works to the place that it does not and just replaced the filename.  Any suggestions as to where I should be looking?

Code:

```
<?php
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword){
global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$servername='xxxx';
$dbusername='xxxx';
$dbpassword='xxxx';
$dbname='xxxx';
connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);

$id=$_GET['id'];
$query   = "SELECT name, type, size, path FROM upload WHERE fileID = '$id'";
$result  = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $size, $filePath) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$name=str_replace(","," - ",$name); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
readfile($filePath);
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code?

Comment: Just edited the post with the code.  The code works in one place but not the other.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of (except my incorrect answer as @Sean correctly mentioned) is to use `ob_clean(); flush();` before `readfile($filePath);`.

Comment: Thanks again tliokos.  Same result though.  Although it does not make sense to me that it would be the code as it works in one place but not the other I am will to entertain any suggestions since none of the things that I would understand it could influence it change (ie same programming, same document, same server, same database etc...)

Comment: Tliokos, you also mentioned Seans Comment but I can not see a comment from Sean.  I am new here...am I missing something?